# Not able to see User record in apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have created a lightning web component that is wrapped in a lightning component.

I am using the lightning component in quick action on the **Contact** object.

On the LWC we are querying the user attached to the current contact.

The class looks like below:

```
public without sharing class GetUserRecordClass {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String printDetails( String argContactId ){
        returnString = getUserRecord( argContactId );
    }

    private static String getUserRecord( String argContactId ){
        try{
            
            User userOnContact = [SELECT Id FROM User Where ContactId = :argContactId LIMIT 1];//Getting error on this line in QA org
            String userId = userOnContact.Id;

            return userId;
        }
        catch( Exception exceptionObject ){
            System.debug( 'Exception occurred=' + exceptionObject.getMessage() );
            System.debug( 'Stack trace=' + exceptionObject.getStackTraceString() );
            throw exceptionObject;    
        }
    }
}
```

The query on User is working fine in my **Dev** org.

I have deployed the code on **QA** org now.

I login into QA with the required user and click on the *Quick Action* button on the **Contact** record.
But getting below error in LWC:
**List has no rows for assignment to SObject**

The class is without sharing.

When I run the query with my user in the *Developer console*, I am able to get the result.

I tried verifying Org wide setting in both org and found a difference.

In Dev Org(Snapshot from Chrome):

[image]

In QA Org(Snapshot from Firefox):
[image]

I am not able to see Site User Visibility check box in the QA org. I believe by checking that, I may be able to fetch record in the QA org Apex.

Can you please let me know where to look else for this?

Comment: Is the Contact record you're testing with portal-enabled in QA? Customer or Partner community?

Comment: The connect is community contact, using which I can log in to the community also.
When I tested community enabled contact in Dev it was working fine.

Comment: the checkbox might be red herring. QA might be on spring release preview (Communities got renamed to Experiences, eh) so if checkbox with same meaning is ticked in both it shouldn't matter. how are you accessing that component? internal user/community user (logged in)/ community guest user? Maybe some critical update around data access? Are you sure argContactId gets passed with not null value?  have similar thing for internal users clicking button to reset passwords of community users and it works well

Comment: Thank @eyescream I just found that somehow the argContactId was hard coded in the JS.

Comment: Hahaha :D oh man. Post it as answer and I'll gladly upvote

Comment: Hahaha Sometimes wallet in your pocket and you are searching in whole house